Representing a periodic strip operator as a tensor product of operators
I hope this question is not trivial, but here goes. I want to consider a bounded operator on $\mathcal{H}=\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}\times \{0,...,N-1\})$ that is a discrete Schrodinger like operator.
Something of the form
$$ [H \psi](n,j)= \psi(n+1, j)+ \psi(n-1, j)+ \psi(n,j+1)\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{ j\neq N-1 \}}+  \psi(n,j-1)\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{ j\neq 0 \}}+ V(n,j)\cdot \psi(n,j), $$
for all $\psi \in \mathcal{H}$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $j\in\{ 0,...,N-1 \}$. From what I understood, we can write $\mathcal{H}\cong \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{C}^N$. I assume further that $V$ is $2$-periodic and real valued. By that I mean that $V(n,j)= V(n+2,j)$.
I believe in that case I can write $H=P_0 A_0 \otimes V_0 + P_1 A_1 \otimes V_1$, where $V_0, V_1 \in M_{N\times N}$ are self-adjoint matrices, $P_0$ is the projection onto the subspace $\overline{span}\big(\{ \delta_n \}_{n\in 2\mathbb{Z}}\big)$ and $P_1 =Id-P_0$ is the projection onto the complement.
I know that there are simple formulae for spectrum of tensor products, such as
$$ \text{spec}(A\otimes B)= \text{spec}(A)\cdot \text{spec}(B) \quad \text{and} \quad \text{spec}(A\otimes I+I\otimes B)= \text{spec}(A)+\text{spec}(B), $$
where $X+Y = \{ x+y:x\in X, y\in Y \}$ and $X\cdot Y=\{ x\cdot y: x\in X, y\in Y \}$. Is there a similar formula for the operator I wrote? Perhaps something of the form $\text{spec}(H)= \text{spec}(P_0A_0)\cdot \text{spec}(V_0)+ \text{spec}(P_1A_1)\cdot \text{spec}(V_1)$?
This seems like a very natural question that I suspect experts in the related fields might have seen before.
